# Convert MongoDB console aggregate to php with array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb-query

i am failing to convert the following mongoDB console command:

```
db.customers.aggregate( [
{ $group : {
    _id: {
        year : { $year: "$since" },        
        month : { $month: "$since" }
    },
    count: { $sum: 1 }
}
}]
);
```

which works into php

```
$customers->aggregate(array(
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array( 'year' => array('$year' => '$since'),
                        'month' => array('$month' => '$since')
            )
        ),
        array(
            'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
            ),
        )
    );
```

which returns `exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`
also already tried `'"$since"'` with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `count` field must be a part of the `group`.

```
$customers->aggregate(array(
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array( 'year' => array('$year' => '$since'),
                        'month' => array('$month' => '$since')
            ),
         'count' => array( '$sum' => 1 )
        )
    ));
```

Comment: damn, thanks! this is kinda reminding me of university using scheme! too many brackets!

Comment: a question aside. the results are pretty randomly sorted with the years and months changing. i tried to add a `{$sort : { year: 1}}` or month, it seems ot change the order but not for the better or actually really ASC/DESC. any clue how to properly sort the results?

Comment: If you are doing a sort after the group stage, you need to use: `$sort:{"_id.year":1}`, which will sort the groups in ascending order.